# HTML Parsing Question: Not able to view and parse the full source code of webhallen.com

Tags: html

I am not able to view and parse the full html content of https://www.webhallen.com/se/product/298259-Sony-2019-55-KD55XG8096BAEP-LED-4K-HDR-Smart-TV

Even in the browser when i click on view page source, the full html code is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

This site, like many others, is enhanced with JavaScript after the initial HTML loads.

Data is loaded via the Fetch API or AJAX.  Template engines run client-side to populate the page.

If you inspect the DOM after the page is loaded, using your browser's developer tools, you'll be able to see all of the elements.

Comment: But how can i parse it using any parsers like BeautifulSoup. Will Selenium work in these kind of websites for parsing data?

Comment: @KICKBUTTOWSKI You need to run some browser engine to run the site.  Ideally in this case, you get proper access from the site rather than scraping it anyway.

Comment: I wanted to write a python script to scrap the title of webhallen products, that's the reason.

Comment: @KICKBUTTOWSKI So, you're asking for help in stealing content?  Sorry, but you could have just asked this question generically.  Why should we help you violate the terms of service of other sites?

Comment: web scraping is legal now